# Error when parsing retrofit2 response

Tags: android, retrofit2, yahoo-api, gson

I'm lost as to where and what I need to change to get this to work.

I'm using [this](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%25YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=) API call to yahoo finance.

This is my retrofit instance:

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://query.yahooapis.com";

    public static Retrofit getClient(){
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Where i make my call:

```
String query = "select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in (\"YHOO\",\"AAPL\",\"GOOG\",\"2MSFT\")&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";

YahooApi yahooApi = ApiClient.getClient().create(YahooApi.class);
Call<GetStockResponse> call = yahooApi.getStock(query);

call.enqueue(new Callback<GetStockResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<GetStockResponse> call, Response<GetStockResponse> response) {
        List<Stock> list = response.body().getQuery().getResults().getList();
        if(list!=null)
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<GetStockResponse> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Interface (YahooApi):

```
@GET("v1/public/yql")
Call<GetStockResponse> getStock(@Query("q") String query);
```

Based on the JSON object I get back, I made the following wrapper classes:

```
public class GetStockResponse {
    @SerializedName("query")
    @Expose
    private Query mQuery;

    public Query getQuery(){
        return mQuery;
    }
}


public class Query {
    @SerializedName("count")
    @Expose
    private String mCount;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private Result mResults;

    public String getCount(){
        return mCount;
    }

    public Result getResults(){
        return mResults;
    }
}

public class Result {
    @SerializedName("quote")
    @Expose
    private List<Stock> mList;

    public List<Stock> getList(){
        return mList;
    }
}

public class Stock {
    @SerializedName("symbol")
    @Expose
    private String mSymbol;
    @SerializedName("Bid")
    @Expose
    private String mBid;
    @SerializedName("Change")
    @Expose
    private String mChange;
    @SerializedName("PercentChange")
    @Expose
    private String mPercentChange;
    @SerializedName("Name")
    @Expose
    private String mName;

    public String getSymbol(){
        return mSymbol;
    }

    public String getBid(){
        return mBid;
    }
    public String getChange(){
        return mChange;
    }

    public String getPercentChange(){
        return mPercentChange;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return mName;
    }
}
```

Any information on what i need to change will be greately appreciated!

Edit* added error message:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'strahinja.udacity.com.stockhawk.model.Query strahinja.udacity.com.stockhawk.model.GetStockResponse.getQuery()' on a null object reference
             at strahinja.udacity.com.stockhawk.fragment.MainFragment$1.onResponse(MainFragment.java:64)
             at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

When I inspected the response, the url that was returned was changed to :

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22,%22AAPL%22,%22GOOG%22,%222MSFT%22)%26format%3Djson%26diagnostics%3Dtrue%26env%3Dstore%253A%252F%252Fdatatables.org%252Falltableswithkeys%26callback%3D
```

Thats all that I've been able to find out.

Comment: can you post full error you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to following (key issue was that the original query string you had that also included other query params)

```
String query = "select * from yahoo.finance.quote where symbol in (\"YHOO\",\"AAPL\",\"GOOG\",\"MSFT\")";
```

Note that I also changed retrofit interface to following to test but you can make those other params dynamic if you need

```
    @GET("v1/public/yql?format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=")
    Call<GetStockResponse> getStock(@Query("q") String query);
```

Comment: I've done the changes you recomended but to no avail. Ive added a link to my code on github if you have time to have a look. Thanks a lot for taking the time to look anyway!

https://github.com/strahinjaajvaz/StockHawk

Comment: Away from laptop now but did you test url generated (in browser)?

Comment: What url are you getting now?

Comment: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=&q=select%2B*%2Bfrom%2Byahoo.finance.quote%2Bwhere%2Bsymbol%2Bin%2B%2528%2522YHOO%2522%252C%2522AAPL%2522%252C%2522GOOG%2522%252C%2522MSFT%2522%2529

Comment: ok, my mistake....you don't actually need to use `URLEncoder.encode` when using Retrofit `@Query` params like this (was mixing up in my head between doing this and case where you manually construct the url (I've updated answer to reflect).  The other change to separate out query though is needed (have expanded on reason above).